# Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am very new to MEAN stack development and only started yesterday. I am trying to get my data back from the database with a call using a resource which is linked to a server side controller. But I am receiving the following console error "Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object"

Angular Controller:

```
app.
    controller('ArticleCtrl',  function($scope, $location, $resource){

        var articles = $resource('/api/articles');

        articles.query(function(result){

            console.log(result);

        });

        $scope.addnew = function(){

            $location.path("/administrationarea/articles/newarticle");

        }


    });
```

Server.js:

```
articlesController = require('./server/controller/article-controller');

app.get('/api/articles', articlesController.list);
app.post('/api/articles', articlesController.create);
```

server side controller:

```
var article = require('../models/articleModel');

module.exports.create = function(req, res){

    var art = new article(req.body);
    art.save( function (err, result){

        res.json(result);

    });

}


module.exports.list = function(req, res){

    article.find({}, function (err, results){

        res.json(results);

    });

}
```

can anyone tell me why this might be happening and maybe offer a solution so that the data is returned as an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is because

```
var articles = $resource('api/articles');
articles.query(function(result){
    // here result should be an array.
        console.log(result);
 });
```

here articles.query expects an array. but not an object.

if your api returns an object then you should use articles.get().

```
articles.get(function(result){
   // here result should be an object but not array
        console.log(result);
    });
```

$resource.query() is used for getting an array from REST API and $resource.get() is used for getting an object from REST API. but in both cases the request type(/method) is 'get' only.

please refer to the [angularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)